# Ruby: creating multivolume Zip archives?

Tags: ruby, zip

I've looked at zip ruby, ruby zip, archive-zip and none of them can create multivolume archives :( Maybe I'm looking wrong? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can shell out to the system:

```
x = '/usr/bin/zip'

`#{x} -b /tmp -s 64k foo bar/` # => /tmp/foo.zip, /tmp/foo.z01, etc.
```

Comment: I know I can use external commands and thats temporary implementation i have (at least I hope its temporary), but still I would like to use some gem or library for that.

Comment: Yeah.. I would've suggested one if I had seen one =/